# Application icon issue

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta, xcode9, xcode9-beta5

Building my application using Xcode 9 developer beta is not showing application icon on devices and simulators running ios 11.

Comment: Did you correctly set icons for app?

Comment: @Masiama yes all the icons added. The icons are showing in iOS 10. but not in iOS 11.

Comment: created test app, see icon, maybe this is bug